# Show that $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z_2}dz_1 \wedge dz_2= dz_2$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, differential-forms

It is well known that $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{1}{z}dz=1$, where $\gamma$ is a circle around the origin $z=0$. My question is somehow similar to this.

Consider the plane $z_1=0$ in $\mathbb C^2$, and let $\gamma_1$ be a contour around this plane.

**Question** Show that $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma_1} \frac{1}{z_2}dz_1 \wedge dz_2= dz_2$

I attempt to calculate this contour integration as usual, but it is very strange with a two-form being integrated. The key point is what is the precise definition for this kind of contour integration.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't make sense, this is not a volume form on the contour. There are no $2$-forms on $1$-manifolds.

Comment: But I still need an explanation

Comment: I think that **is** the explanation:  automatically $dz_1$ and $dz_2$ are linearly dependent by dimensional considerations, so their wedge is $dz_1\wedge dz_1\bigg|_{\gamma}=0$ so the integral is $0$.

Comment: But the answer is $dz_2$

Comment: That's what they say it is, but you can easily see this is not true: 
$$dz_1\wedge dz_2 = z_1'(\gamma_1(t))\gamma_1'(t)\,dt\wedge z_2'(\gamma_1(t))\gamma_1'(t)\,dt= z_1'(\gamma_1(t))z_2'(\gamma_1(t))\gamma_1'(t)^2dt\wedge dt=0$$

Comment: All you folks who don't think it makes sense should learn about integration over the fiber, for example. But, @Hans, you have a typo. This should be $1/z_1$, not $1/z_2$.

Answer (score 3):

You can interpret the differential 2-form $dz_1 \wedge dz_2$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ also as a 1-form on $\mathbb{C}^2$ with value in $T^*\mathbb{C}^2$. As such, you would be able to integrate such a form on 1-submanifolds in order to get a 0-form on $\mathbb{C}^2$ with value in $T^*\mathbb{C}^2$, i.e. a usual 1-form.

(To get a sense of what this means, recall from calculus classes the integration of the velocity vector in order to get the displacement of a point particle. How did you defined such an integration, if not as the 'usual' Riemann integration of a vector-valued function instead of a scalar one? Here, over the point $q \in \mathbb{C}^2$, the 1-form takes value in the vector space $T^*_q \mathbb{C}^2 \simeq \mathbb{C}^2 \simeq \mathbb{R}^4$, so the integration of such a 1-form is not so very different from integration in calculus.)

Somewhat put differently, imagine you were to integrate $dz_1 \wedge dz_2$ over the 2-manifold $\gamma_1 \times \gamma_2$ where $\gamma_j \subset [z_j=0]$. In practice, you would compute this integral through two iterated integrals, first performing the integration over each slice $\gamma_1 \times \{p\}$ with $p \in \gamma_2$, then the integral over $\gamma_2$. In some respect, your question concerns the meaning of the first of the two iterated integrals. Since the end result has to be a scalar, the integrand of the second of the two iterated integrals has to be a 1-form on $\gamma_2$. This suggests that the result of integrating the 2-form over each slice is a 1-form. In the present case, since the form $dz_2$ does not depends on $p \in \gamma_2$, you can give a well-defined meaning to your integral (as the value of the integral over any slice), and the result is indeed $dz_2$.

---

This explanation was more about integration the form $dz_1 \wedge dz_2$ over a curve $\gamma_1 \subset [z_1=0]$, but this is not what your question is about.

Nevertheless, one can still interpret $(1/z_1) dz_1 \wedge dz_2$ (mind the difference with what is written in the question; is it a typo?) as a 1-form over $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus [z_1 = 0]$ taking value in $T^*\mathbb{C}^2$ (the specific value being $dz_2$). Let $\gamma$ be a closed curve around the plane $[z_1 = 0]$. By (a somewhat generalized) Stokes theorem, we can assume that $\gamma \subset [z_2 = 0]$. In this case, the 'intuitive' explanation I gave tells us more easily that the integral is $((2\pi i)^{-1} \oint_{\gamma} z_1^{-1}dz_1) \wedge dz_2 = dz_2$.

---

The book *Principles of Algebraic Geometry* by Griffiths and Harris discusses  differential forms with value in more general vector spaces (and vector bundles). This is also applied to complex calculus in higher dimension. The book *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology* by Bott and Tu discusses 'fiber integration', where one integrates a $k$-differential form over a $l$-submanifold with $l \le k$ to get a $(k-l)$-differential form with value in the appropriate space.

These references are possibly too technical for your needs, so I preferred to give an informal answer here.

Comment: @AdamHughes The vector space $\mathbb{C}^2$ has a natural metric (and a natural connection), so one can easily identify the many $T^*_q\mathbb{C}^2$'s with $\mathbb{C}^2$ itself. As such, the 2-form $dz_1 \wedge dz_2$ can be interpreted as the 1-form $\alpha$ whose value at $q \in \mathbb{C}^2$ is $\alpha_q = f(q)(dz_1)_q$ with $f(q) \in \mathbb{C}^2$ being identified with the 1-form $(dz_2)_q \in T^*_q\mathbb{C}^2$. The (meaning of the) integration of such a 1-form should not cause any real problem.

Comment: I figured it out after I asked, that's why I deleted my original comment, but I wanted to acknowledge your response with gratitude. It seems we came up with different interpretations of the op's question, this was just a more general query since I didn't see a canonical choice, but as you say we can make choices to make the normalization constant $1$ as needed. Cheers!

Comment: @AdamHughes Your comment was more than welcome. It made me notice that I had not really answered the question, and I also noticed what I expect to be a typo in the question (so possibly I still don't have given an answer, but then I would argue with you that the integral is zero). It is a difficult thing to understand differential forms and the peculiar way in which they are integrated. I was very pleased when I learnt about their integration over arbitrary submanifolds, as I think this gives a more geometric and closer to usual view of integration. Our comments present both interpretations.

Comment: Griffiths and Harris :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you! I don't know where my thoughts were!